# PHP: How to create a timestamp from pattern H:i (17:45)?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, mktime

my current code:

```
<?php
    $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i", $_POST["datetime"]);
    echo $timestamp; // works!
?>
```

Now I've a form with two fields: date and time, separated.

```
<?php
    $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", $_POST["date"]);
    echo $timestamp; // works!

    $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $_POST["time"]);
    echo $timestamp; // doesn't work (error below)!

    // Edit: 
    /* Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in */
?>
```

I would like to avoid using explode() with mktime(). That feels dirty and I think there could be another, clean way.

How would you create the timestamp from format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with the 2nd code?

Comment: @Neal Please check out the Fatal Error I just added to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the date and time from `$_POST["date"]` and `$_POST["time"]` Use following

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y H:i", $_POST["date"]." ".$_POST["time"]);
```

If you want to kow the number of seconds from midnight for that particular time you can however use this,

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd H:i", date("Ymd")." ".$_POST["time"]);
```

Comment: That's it. I missed the forest for the trees. Shame on me!

Comment: Not true, `DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $_POST["time"]);` will work, but not necessarily produce the desired results. See [this example](http://3v4l.org/9W4kA).

Comment: @nickb thanks. So it only works on 5.3.x or higher. I just removed statement. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The timestamp requires a date in order to be calculated, and there isn't one available to use.

Comment: This isn't 100% true, `createFromFormat()` will set the other fields of the date to the current date/time in its default behavior (without the `!` or `|` format modifier). See [this example](http://3v4l.org/9W4kA).

Answer (score 1):

Use Date time's [settime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) method

```
$timestamp = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.Y", '10.10.2012');
$timestamp->setTime(17,12);
var_dump($timestamp);
```

Gives

```
object(DateTime)#1142 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-10-10 17:12:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```